# How to increase/decrease the values of multiple inputs in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to provide a variable number of inputs, and each of them needs to have the same functionality to increase its value on key up and decrease it on key down when they have focus (no mouse interaction, only keyboard). The input must be a positive number between 0 and 9. The framework is Angular 7.

I have the basic functionality for a single input working, as per code below. I have seen solutions close to my need, but always for a single input or using separate components, or using jQuery. I'm seeking an Angular/TS solution. This is a prototype, so I'm free to change the code as needed.

The HTML code:

```
<input (keydown)="numberInput($event)" type="number" [(ngModel)]="offsetValue_1">
<input (keydown)="numberInput($event)" type="number" [(ngModel)]="offsetValue_2">
[...]
<input (keydown)="numberInput($event)" type="number" [(ngModel)]="offsetValue_5">
```

The TS code for the first input, which obviously I don't want to repeat for each 'offsetValue_X':

```
numberInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.which === this.KEY_UP) {
          if (this.offsetValue_1 < 9) {
              this.offsetValue_1 = this.offsetValue_1 + 1;
          }
    } else if (event.which === this.KEY_DOWN) {
          if (this.offsetValue_1 > 0) {
              this.offsetValue_1 = this.offsetValue_1 - 1;
          }
    }
}
```

Each input needs to have its own value when the form is submitted. Obviously I want to avoid duplicating the same function for each input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div *ngFor="let input of inputs; let i = index">
    <input [placeholder]="'Input ' + i" type="number" #numInput (keydown)="numberInput($event, numInput.value)" >
</div>

// TypeScript
numberInput(evt, val) {
    console.log(evt, val);
}
```

`inputs` could be an array of anything that lets you loop through it and put a variable number of inputs on the page. Use a template variable, `#numInput`, to put the input's value into the function. You could also pass the `i` variable for the index into that function as well.

As a side note, if you use keydown, the first time the user pushes the up arrow, when the input starts at 0, the function will get 0 (or nothing, actually) in the function, but the input will show 1. Then when they hit the up key again, the function will get 1 as the value input. I would consider using `keyup` instead.